# Can I rename lib.rs to the crate name?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Right now I'm working on a project with multiple separate crates.

I would prefer lib.rs to be renamed to the crate's name itself, as when I open multiple at the same time it takes me an extra second to find the one I'm looking for, not a big deal just curious if it's possible or a good idea.

[image: many lib.rs files open at the same time in ide]

`ne_log/lib.rs` into: `ne_log/ne_log.rs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in each `Cargo.toml` add a `lib` section with the desired path:

```toml
[lib]
path = "src/some_other_file.rs"
```

Read more here: [Cargo Targets](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#configuring-a-target)

As to whether its a good idea or not; it will make your file structure non-standard, but the option is available since there are plenty of non-standard workflows. Use your own discretion.